# AJAX works in jQuery but not in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a small form where when the username field is being blurred or out of focus, AJAX checks if the entered username is already recorded in the database. The problem is that the AJAX in jQuery works, but not in vanilla JS. I need to know what line or part of my code did I get it wrong.

HTML

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input class="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" autocomplete="off">
    <span class="uname_notice"></span><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$('.username').blur(function() {
    var username = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {username: username},
        success: function(responseText) {
            $('.uname_notice').text(responseText);
        }
    })
});
```

Vanilla JS

```
document.querySelector('.username').onblur = function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "process.php", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            document.querySelector('.uname_notice').textContent = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: The `data: ...` part is missing

Comment: How and where can I add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send data along with the HTTP request.

```
document.querySelector('.username').onblur = function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var data = new FormData();
    var username = document.getElementsByClassName('username')[0].value;
    data.append('username', username);
    xhr.open("POST", "process.php", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            document.querySelector('.uname_notice').textContent = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Comment: what is `FormData()` for?

Comment: It worked! Thanks! But I was not the one who gave you the negative vote

Comment: But I need to know what is `FormData()` for?

Comment: Formdata to a JavaScript object that lets you submit payloads as part of post request .

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify post value. Try to use this:

```
document.querySelector('.username').onblur = function() {

    var params = 'username='+this.value;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "process.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            document.querySelector('.uname_notice').textContent = xhr.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhr.send(params);
};
```